# Why is puppet not finding my environment module path?

Tags: puppet

I have a simple environment set up with puppet. On the master I have

```
[root@ak-puppetm develop]# pwd
/etc/puppet/environments/develop

[root@ak-puppetm develop]# puppet config print modulepath --section master --environment develop
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

[root@ak-puppetm develop]# ls -lah
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 5 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 akropp akropp 6.1K Jul 16 15:16 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 4 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:16 files
drwxr-xr-x 2 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:16 manifests
drwxr-xr-x 3 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:20 modules

[root@ak-puppetm develop]# ls -lah modules/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 akropp akropp 4.0K Jul 16 15:08 domains
[root@ak-puppetm develop]#
```

And yet you can see that the module path doesn't seem to contain develop?

If I move my module code to `/etc/puppet/modules` then puppet finds my classes just fine.

I even tried putting

```
modulepath=$confdir/environments/$environment/modules:$confdir/modules
```

Into the puppet.conf but it didn't find it still and just got deprecation warnings instead

My environment though is working, I have a manifest in there and it works great for nodes tagged with the `develop` environment. Just can't seem to get the modules to pick up

Comment: can you share your `puppet.conf [master]` section ?

Comment: I had another gotcha in this context - dash symbol is not allowed! Only  \A[a-z0-9_]+\Z pattern

Answer (score 3):

Inside `/etc/puppet/environments/develop` you need a file name `environment.conf`. Content of that file can be something similar to this :

```
modulepath = /etc/puppet/environments/develop/modules:$basemodulepath
```

Comment: The environment conf should not be strictly needed. It is good practice to use relative paths in there, so that changes to central configuration don't break your environments.

Answer (score 3):

The global `modulepath` setting is inconsequential once you switch to environment directories. So the important question is, does

```
puppet master --configprint environmentpath
```

yield `/etc/puppet/environments`.

**Update** after feedback from the OP:

Since you have not yet activated directory environments, your `/etc/puppet/environments/develop` does not in fact spawn an actual `develop` environment. You'd need to define this environment explicitly in `puppet.conf`, including its `manifest` and `modulepath` settings.

Don't do that, though. If your filesystem layout is ready for environment directories, you should add *that* setting to `puppet.conf` instead.

```
[main]
environmentpath=/etc/puppet/environments
```

Comment: I posted that result in the original question. It didn't show up the right module path so I'm not sure why it's not picking up

Comment: No, you did not. Your question concerns itself with the `modulepath` setting, which is most likely defunct in your setup.

Comment: I see, I misread your question. It doesn't print anything out, unfortunately